# Extract POST data in Node.js without knowing the name of the input

Tags: node.js, express

How can I get the value of an input element sent in a POST form which I don't know the name?

The app generates some input elements with a random names:

```
<input name="id_1" value="val1" type="text">
<input name="id_632" value="val2" type="text">
<input name="id_9345" value="val3" type="text">
```

In express, I could recover the value using the body-parser like this:

```
let foo = req.body.id_1;
```

But I can't know beforehand the name "id_1". Assuming that I could get an array with the random values:

```
let myArray = ["id_1","id_632","id_9345"];
```

Can I get the values of the POST form in a similar way like this?:

```
  let myInput = myArray[0];
  let myValue = req.body[myInput];
  console.log(myValue); // Should output -> val1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `body-parser` then `req.body` is an object. You can make an array out of it and use it.

```
const myArray = Object.keys(req.body);

let myInput = myArray[0];
let myValue = req.body[myInput];
console.log(myValue);
```

You can easily do this.